# How I can save the output in a text file

Tags: python, output

I use the library TextRazor to analyze a text and save it in a text file but when I open the file it's empty

```
import os 
textrazor.api_key = ""
client = textrazor.TextRazor(extractors=["word","entities", "topics","sentence","words"])
response = client.analyze("Twenty-four isolates (60%) were associated with pneumonia, 14 (35%) with upper respiratory tract infections, and 2 (5%) with bronchiolitis. Cough (82.5%), fever (75%), and malaise (58.8%) ")
for entity in response.entities():
    print(entity.id, entity.relevance_score, entity.confidence_score, entity.freebase_types)
cmd = os.popen('ls -w').read() # Récupération de la sortie de ls -a dans la variable cmd
print(cmd) # Affichage de la sortie
with open('monfichier.txt', 'w') as file:
        s=str(cmd)
        file.write(s)
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing your API key from your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls -w` is not a valid command as an integer is needed after the `-w`. Furthermore, do not use `os.popen`: it is not portable. Use the Python API instead (see `os.walk`).

Comment: I use os.walk but I have this message in the file:                                                      
   <generator object walk at 0x000002CE9512A6D0>

Comment: This is because the result is a *Python generator*. You can convert to a list using `list(...)`. Note that `os.walk` iterate over the files recursively. If you do not want this, you can use `os.scanfile` instead. For example: `list(e.name for e in os.scandir('.'))`. If you want a multi-line string as a result, you can use `'\n'.join(e.name for e in os.scandir('.'))`.